# What's a way to retrive the "path" portion of dxlHere() and go up two dirs?

Tags: ibm-doors

We are regularly setting up new DOORS installations on standalone networks, and each of these networks use slightly different drive mappings and installation directories.  We have a set of DXL scripts that we copy over to each network that uses DOORS, but these DXL scripts reference some Microsoft Word templates that are used as the basis for custom-developed module export scripts.

We no longer have a DXL expert in-house, and I'm trying to make the scripts more portable so that they no 
longer contain hard-coded file paths.  Because we copy all of  the templates and DXL files in a pre-defined directory structure, I can use the `dxlHere()` function to figure out the execution path of the DXL script, which would print something like this:

```
<C:\path\to\include\file\includeFile.inc:123>
<C:\path\to\include\file\includeFile.inc:321>
<Line:2>
<Line:5>
<Line:8>
```

What I'd like to do is extract everything before `file\includeFile.inc:123>`, excluding the starting `<`.  Then I want to append `templates\template.dotx`.

For example, the final result would be:

```
C:\path\to\inclue\template.dotx
```

Are there any built-in DXL functions to handle string manipulation like this?  Is regex the way to go?  If so, what regexp would be appropriate to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this... kind of working.

dxlHere is something I don't work with much, but this seems to work- as long as it's saved to a an actual dxl or inc file (i.e. not just run from the editor)

```
string s = dxlHere()
string s2 = null
string s3 = null
Regexp r = regexp2 ( "\\..*:.*> $" )
Regexp r2 = regexp2 ( "/" )
if ( r s ) {
    s2 = s[ 1 : ( ( start ( 0 ) ) - 1 ) ]
    s3 = s[ 1 : ( ( start ( 0 ) ) - 1 ) ]
    int x = 0
    while ( r2 s2 ) {
        x++
        s2 = s2[ ( ( start ( 0 ) ) + 1 ) : ]
    }
    int z = 0
    for ( y = 0; y <= length( s3 ); y++ ){
        if ( s3[y] == '/' ) {
            z++
            if ( z == ( x - 2 ) ) {
                s = s3[ 0 : y ]
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

print s
```

So we're doing a single regexp to check if we have a valid 'location', then running through it to find ever '/' character, then leaving off the last 2 of them.

Hope this helps!